# ExpressionEngine conditional based on Google Analytics URL tags

Tags: google-analytics, expressionengine

I am trying to create a conditional statement in ExpressionEngine that displays content based on the utm_source variable in a URL with Google Analytics campaign information.

If, for example, the url is

"www.mysite.com/landingpage/?utm_source=One" some content would be displayed

and if the url is

"www.mysite.com/landingpage/?utm_source=Two" some other content would be displayed.

To get started, I tried:

```
{if segment_3 == "?utm_source=One" }
    Do something special
{/if}
```

But ExpressionEngine does not appear to recognize the URL tag info as a 3rd segment.  Any ideas as to how I might approach this?

Thanks,

-Michael

Comment: To my the best of my knowledge you would have to capture the query string in PHP (or maybe someone has written a plugin that would do this). I don't believe you can do this in vanilla EE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One I found out about today: [Mo Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables)

Then your code would look like this:

```
{if "{get:utm_source}" == "One"}
    Do something special
{if:elseif "{get:utm_source}" == "Two"}
    Do something extra special
{if:else}
    Do something boring
{/if}
```

There are others [like this one](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/server-variable) that I've used before but just does what it says on the tin. Whereas Mo Variables does a whole lot more.

Comment: Thank you Peter and AllInOne.  I did it (rather untidily) with PHP "REQUEST_URI", but Mo Variables looks perfect (and will make the template code much more intuitive).